# return an array of structs from a function executed by a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have an array of structure of 2 strings which I return from a function.
But this function is called as part of the callable function of a thread

```
struct mystruct* myfunc(char* param1, int param2, int param3);

std::thread t1(myfunc, param1, param2, param3);
```

I understood from the std::thread documentation that the return value from myfunc will be ignored. But I need this data. Is there a way to get this data? I read there is something like std::promise and std::future but really couldn't understand what they are. Can anyone help me out with a simple example to achieve this?

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Esash

Answer (score 4):

As you said, the proper way to do this is probably using `std::future` and `std::async`. As [cppreferece](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) sais:

> The class template std::future provides a mechanism to access the result of asynchronous operations

This is where `std::async` comes in. The function `myfunc` will be launched using `std::async`, which will return a "future" value (which we will catch later). Once you have the asynchronous function launched, you just have to ask your `std::future` variable to get that return value whenever it's ready. Your code would look something like this:

```
// This will call myfunc asynchronously and assign its future return value to my_fut
std::future<mystruct*> my_fut = std::async(myfunc, param1, param2, param3);

/* 
   Do some work
*/

// We are ready to assign the return value to a variable, so we ask
// my_fut to get that "future" value we were promised.
mystruct* mptr = my_fut.get();
```

I think that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall do the same but with the async flag as well.. These make more sense to me now.. really thanks a lot guys.. :)

Comment: Normally, the compiler decides if creating a new thread is worth or not (without the flags). If the job is really small, creating a new thread may be slower. Anyway, most of the times it will run in another thread, but you want 100% be asynchronously, use the flag and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

As @Fransisco Callego Salido already said the only way to do what you want is to use std::async, but be careful std::async does not guarantee that your function will be run asynchronously. 
As [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com) says.

> The template function async runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.

In order to run myfunc asynchronously you have to pass another parameter to the constructor of std::async, the policy. Right now there are 3 policies

- std::launch::async - Guarantees that you function will be run on a new thread.
- std::launch::deferred  - Your function will be called on the current thread when you decide the call the member function of the returned future.
- std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred - It's up to the implementation to decide if you function will be run on a new thread.

Another thing to remember is, that the policy is always passed as the first parameter to std::async's constructor, if you forget to pass it the std::launch::async | std::launch:deferred policy will be used!
So in order guarantee an that your function is executed on a new thread you have to call it like this.

```
std::future<mystruct*> myfunc_future=std::async(std::launch::async, myfunc, param1, param2, param3);
mystruct* myfunc_result=myfunc.get();
```

Comment: this is great! thanks a lot. Saw the same in cppreference but really couldn't understand any of this. These explanations make more sense now. Thanks a lot guys.. Will implement using async flag to ensure my function runs on a separate thread since that's what i want..